# Is finding the greatest common divisor of two polynomials NP-hard?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, nonlinear-system

Given two multivariate polynomials over a unique factorization domain R of at most `n` terms, is it possible to find the greatest common divisor in polynomial time with respect to `n`?

I have skimmed a few papers related to the polynomial greatest common divisor but failed to find any argument about the time complexity of the algorithm.

If it is not NP-hard. I'm also interested in the problem of finding GCD between two algebraic expressions that consist of only standard additions, multiplications, exponentiations, paratheses, real numbers, and variables. For example:

$$x^2(x+2y)^2+y^2(y+2x)^2-2x^2y^2,$$
$$(x^2-1)^2-(y^2-1)^2+2(xy+1)(x+y)(x-y)$$

The greatest common divisor of the above two formulae is $(x+y)^3$.

Is this problem NP-hard with respect to the number of variables and operators used to describe the expression? I guess it is because computing the expansion itself could be NP-hard as the number of terms in the expansion can grow exponentially as the length of expressions grows. But I have no argument about why computing GCD has to be performed on the expansion.

What I need eventually is to prove a problem that is harder than the above two is NP-hard. Any argument about the hardness of the above problems or similar problems (with looser constraints) could help.

Comment: If all constraints are removed, as you say, why should the polynomial ring be a UFD, or even a GCD domain?

Comment: If there are no restrictions on the coefficients of the polynomials, it could take time exponential in $n$ just to enter the data, much less compute anything with it.

Comment: "Polynomial time" with respect to what measure of the problem to be solved? If you can't define that, then you are not asking a meaningful question in complexity theory.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry for the ambiguous description. I just modified the constraints to make the problem more clear.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have changed the problem to restrict the coefficients to be real numbers. Would the problem still be NP-hard?

Comment: @RobArthan "Polynomial-time" is with respect to the number of operators and operands used to describe the expression. Feel free to bring suggestions if the question is not clear still.

Comment: I have a couple of points to make: (1) finding GCDs in $R[x, y, z, \ldots]$ has finding GCDs in $R$ as a special case - are you expecting your algorithm for the former to be parametrized by an algorithm for the second? (This relates to Gerry's comment.) (2) NP is a class of decision problems, whereas GCD-finding is a function problem, so you need to clarify what you mean when you ask whether GCD-finding is NP hard (it may well be that GCD-finding is in FNP if (or iff) GCD-recognising is in NP - and the latter might be a more tractiable question to investigate).